# Delete from two table in one query

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have two table Images and Note both is having Noteid column so how delete Noteid = 2 in both table...My query is `"delete from Note,Images where Noteid = "2""` but it not working...

Comment: At least add some detail like , CoreData or sql , Piece of code nobody can help you from only this detail

Comment: its question for iphone and sqlite which I tag it you must watch it...

Comment: and i got  two answer for it...k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write two queries as below to delete from two tables

```
  DELETE FROM Note WHERE Noteid = '2';
  DELETE FROM Images WHERE Noteid  = '2';
```

This may be work for you.

Comment: yes its work but for that I make two different function and call..why we not make it in one query..

Comment: NO you cant do that easily because in sql syntax you can add only one table name after FROM keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from Note, Images where Noteid = 2
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I am using SQLite it give error :SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: delete from Note, Text where Noteid = 2
 [ near ",": syntax error ]

Comment: then you may have to user 2 separate queries to delete the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a trigger for this.

```
//This will work for you open your databse in any database managers and create this trigger
CREATE TRIGGER Images_delete AFTER DELETE ON Note
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Images WHERE Noteid = old.Noteid;
END
```

You just need to delete from Note table.

For more information read here

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html